# Visualising triangulation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, visualisation

I teach a non-geographical technical course, and the topic will be triangulation (..of suspects via mobile phone signals while using an archived well-known case). Since the system in questioned is GSM, we/they used the TA value (distance from tower quantized from [0:63], where each step is ~550 meters). So if TA is (eg.) 10, the distance from the tower is (in an ideal case) from "10*550m" to "10*550m+549.99m".

I have coordinates of three towers in lat,lon (WGS84), I have the TA values, and I would like to draw three donut shapes (inner radius=ta*550m, outer (ta+1)*550m) which would ideally intersect in one relatively small area. I also have a raster map (satellite images). I have already verified the raster layer and the basestation points are visualised OK, but I have no idea how to draw the 'donuts' (except photoshop and eyeballing it).

What would be the simplest way to visualise that in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! I have few questions:
1) Do you have a TA value for each tower? If yes, are they stored somewhere or you haven't a digital source?
2) In which UTM zone are your towers? Their coordinates are stored somewhere or you haven't a digital source?
3) A possible solution could be proposed with a Python script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [Multi Ring Buffer plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Multi_Ring_Buffer/) to get your 'donuts'.

As it's in meters, you should use a UTM CRS, rather than one whose units are in degrees. I'm in the UK so I used OSGB (27700) for this example. You WILL need to project your lat/lon coordinates into a UTM projection - which one depends on where your masts are in the world.

Set up each mast on its own layer - one point per layer. Run the plugin on each mast layer as follows, using settings like this:-

[image]

You should now have three sets of concentric circles/rings, like so. Each ring is 550m wide.

[image]

Now, on each mast's concentric circle layer, count out the rings from the middle - a TA value of 0 is the innermost circle, 1 is the next band out, 2 is the one after that, and so on.

Use the **select tool** to select that ring. Save the circle as a new layer, making sure you **select "save only selected features"** (this is very important) and also make sure you save the layer using the UTM projection.

Once you have that for all three layers, you should see something like this. I chose a TA value of 4 for all 3 masts, but you could use a different TA for each mast if you wanted to.

[image]

To get the intersection of all 3,

- select the ring layer from mast 1 and use **intersect** with the ring layer from mast 2
- select the output from the last step, and use **intersect** with the ring layer from mast 3.

You should now have the shape of the zone where all 3 overlap...

[image]