# Calculating a coordinate based on approximate distances from known locations

Tags: distance, coordinates

My goal is to calculate a position based on approximate distances from known nearby locations.

The distance observations include inherent error.  The number of known locations is often 12 or more.

Is there a approach for calculating a position that decreases the impact of the distance errors?

Comment: If you compute each "location" as an error ellipse, you could convolve the resulting ellipses.  Lots of [research](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PUBS_LIB/AlgorithmsForConfidenceCirclesAndEllipses_TR_NOS107_CGS3.pdf) on this topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multilateration Code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97501/multilateration-code) or  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/trilateration-algorithm-for-n-amount-of-points

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/221473/120129